# Change font color base on child class

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to change the font color if it have specific class.

HTML:

```
    <p class="status">  
      test
      <span class="has-this">test</span> (all turn to red)
    </p>

    <p class="status"> 
      <span>test</span> 
    </p>
```

SCSS:

```
.status {
        font-size: 25px;
        color: blue;
        height: 30px;
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        .has-this & {
            color: red;
        }
    }
```

If it has 'has-this' class inside I want to change font color to red.
Is it possible to achieve this by using css only ?(no js)
The status dynamically generate some with has-this some not .

Here my codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbGyZm

Comment: With the code you have provided, I don't think this is possible without JavaScript. Can you not add the class `has-this` to `status` instead?

Comment: no, the status dynamically generate some with has-this some not .

Answer (score 0):

Add below Css:

```
.status span {
  color: gray;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to re-read the OP. All this will do is make the text in `span`s which are children to `.status` `grey`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the & character just do this:

```
.status {
    ....
    .has-this {
      ....
    }
}
```

The & character represents the parent selector and renders it as it is when scss is compiled, for example:

```
.status {
   ...
    &:after{
   ...
   }
}
```

becomes:

```
.status{ ... }
.status:after{ ... }
```

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work . I wan to change entire status to red not only that one word . I can simply remove & for change that one word .

Comment: Oh sorry just noted that has-this is a child class which means you dont need the & character at all

Comment: I wan to change entire status to red not only that one word . I can simply remove & for change that one word .

Comment: also your spelling is incorrect in html ... you have written `clss` instead of `class`

Comment: I already fix it in codepen .

Comment: If you want to change the whole word dont define .has-this.... simple apply color to the first selector ? [Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOdXEd)

Comment: that status dynamically render. I want to check if arrow upward(has-this) I wan the whole status turn to red else leave it blue.

Comment: then add the .has-this class on the parent p tag not the child span tag

Answer (score 0):

i have done the code you can see...
HTML part

```
  <span class="a">test</span> 
  <h1 class="h1">jkcldjf</h1>



  <span class="a">test</span> k

</div>
```

SCSS part...

```
.status {
        font-size: 25px;
        color: blue;
        height: 30px;
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        & .a {
            color: green;
        }
       & .h1
         {
           color:green;
         }
    }
```

Comment: not even close to my question

Answer (score 0):

Edit Your CSS like

```
.status {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: blue;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    .has-this {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Comment: OP wants all text within `.status` to be `red` not just text inside `.has-this`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector